# Vite - Separate chunk for fonts

Tags: vue.js, rollup, vite

I am building a library that contains components and some shared CSS, like a design system.

The problem is that it is not separating the fonts in different chunks, instead, it is inlining them in the font as base 64, so the CSS file gets huge!

```
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { resolve } from 'path';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, 'src/index.ts'),
      name: 'design-system',
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ['vue'],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: 'Vue',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: '@', replacement: '/src' },
    ],
  },
});
```

I already tried to place it in root/public, but it didn't work.

I have a file _fonts.css which import fonts like so

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Inter;
  src: url('/public/fonts/Inter-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

And then I have a main.scss that imports it

```
// main.scss
@import 'normalize';
@import 'themes';
@import 'fonts';
```

Any idea on how to split it?

Comment: Did you manage to split the font chunk ? I'm looking exactly for that

Comment: I migrated the lib to webpack. Looks like right now there is no way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to accomplish this in a library we're working on by placing the fonts in the special `public` directory (see: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory).

Long story short placing assets in there makes Vite copy them over without any  actual transformation and/or renaming.

First of all place your font files in `public/fonts/`.

Then add the following to `vite.config.ts`:

```
{
  root: './',
  publicDir: 'public',
}
```

This was necessary although it should be a default setting.

Then my font declaration looks like this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: MyFont;
  src: url('./fonts/myfont.woff2');
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

But - this is for the library mode. In case you're building an app just start the font URL path with `/` instead of `./`.